# should we choose async await over Promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, v8

I know that the `async await` is the new `Promise` in the town and it is a new way to write asynchronous code and I also know that

We didn’t have to write `.then`, create an anonymous function to handle the response

`Async/await` makes it finally possible to handle both synchronous and asynchronous errors with the same construct, good old try/catch

The error stack returned from a `promise` chain gives no clue of where the error happened. However, the error stack from async/await points to the function that contains the error

AND SO ON...

but 
here I have done a simple bench mark https://repl.it/repls/FormalAbandonedChimpanzee

In the benchmark I have run 2 loops for 1 million times.
In first loop I am calling a function that is returning 1
in another function I am calling a function that is throwing 1 as an exception.

the time taken by first loop which is calling a function that is returning 1 is almost half of the function that is throwing 1 as error.

Which shows that time taken by `throw` is almost double of the time taken by `return`

```
node v7.4 linux/amd64

return takes 1.233seconds
1000000
throw takes 2.128seconds
1000000
```

**Benchmark Code Below**

```
function f1() {
  return 1;
}

function f2() {
  throw 1;
}

function parseHrtimeToSeconds(hrtime) {
    var seconds = (hrtime[0] + (hrtime[1] / 1e9)).toFixed(3);
    return seconds;
}

var sum = 0;
var start = 0;
var i = 0;

start = process.hrtime();
for (i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
  try {
    sum += f1();
  } catch (e) {
    sum += e;
  }
}
var seconds = parseHrtimeToSeconds(process.hrtime(start));
console.log('return takes ' + seconds + 'seconds');
console.log(sum);




sum = 0;
start = process.hrtime();
for (i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
  try {
    sum += f2();
  } catch (e) {
    sum += e;
  }
}

seconds = parseHrtimeToSeconds(process.hrtime(start));
console.log('throw takes ' + seconds + 'seconds');
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Since `await` awaits a `promise`, the premise of your question is really kind of wrong.  It's really `await` vs. `.then()`, not `await` vs. `promise`.  When using `await` with an async operation, there's always a promise involved because any `async` function returns a promise so you aren't avoiding a promise when using `await`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your benchmark has nothing to do with the performance between `async/await` vs raw promises. All I can see is that throwing an error takes a longer time to compute. This is expected.

Back to the main question, should use `async/await` rather than `.then` with raw promises?

Keep in mind that `async/await` is merely syntactic sugar over raw promises, so there shouldn't be much impact on the overall performance. However, it does make your code more linear which removes a lot of cognitive overhead from the developer.

The conclusion is use what you prefer. Promises can be polyfill'd but new syntaxes cannot, so you might want to keep that in mind when deciding which style to use.

---

Some misunderstanding:

> The error stack returned from a promise chain gives no clue of where the error happened

That is not true. A quick check with:

```js
function error() {
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
        res(undefined()); // uh oh
    });
}

error().then(console.log, e => console.log("Uh oh!", e.stack));
```

shows the entire error stack including the location.

Comment: You are quite correct and I agree with you and I just need to confirm one more thing, Suppose if I have some async validations `e.g. checking the availability of user name, email, phone number.` In case any of these validation fails, I will have to use `throw` in the `async function`. so that the `await` will receive the error. In promise I do not have to use throw I just `reject` is't it `reject` vs `throw`. On server where a single line of code may get executed millions of time. Pardon me for my ignorance, I know this sounds silly.. but cannot resist. Thanks for sparing your time to answer.

Comment: @VikasBansal Throwing an error inside an `async` function might be handled differently by the interpreter so you will have to test it out to be sure. Try using both of them in some actual testing environment and analyze the time they take afterwards.

Comment: @VikasBansal A `throw` in a function marked with the `async` keyword is compiled to a `.catch()`. Remember, the `async` keyword always returns a `Promise`. You can call an `async` function using the `foo().then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError)` because as mentioned, a function marked with `async` **always** returns a `Promise`. Similarly, any `Promise` you have can always be used with `await`.

Answer (score 8):

As most things go, the answer is "it depends".

Before talking about performance, the more important aspect is the maintainability of the code, and limitation of `async`/`await` vs raw `Promise`.

`async`/`await` is a great way to execute asynchronous code sequentially, while `Promise` enables you to run asynchronous code concurrently.

```
async function foo() {
  const a = await backend.doSomething()
  const b = await backend.doAnotherThing()
  return a + b
}
```

In the code above, `backend.doAnotherThing()` will not be executed until `backend.doSomething()` has returned. On the other hand:

```
function foo() {
  Promise.all([backend.doSomething(), backend.doAnotherThing()])
    .then(([a, b]) => {
       return a + b
    })
}
```

will execute both calls, and wait for both to complete.

As you mentioned about the benefits of `async`/`await`, I personally use it extensively. Except for the cases above.

If you need performance and to you, the performance difference between `async`/`await` vs `Promise` is more important than the readability benefit of `async`/`await` over `Promise`, by all mean go ahead.

As long as it is a conscious choice, you should be fine.

UPDATE: as mentioned by Derek 朕會功夫

You can get parallel execution with `async`/`await` by:

```
async function foo() {
  const p1 = backend.doSomething()
  const p2 = backend.doAnotherThing()
  return await p1 + await p2
}
```

Comment: It's nitpicking at this point, but your async example can be [rewritten as such](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/e3wwfc2p/) to execute them concurrently. Both `async/await` and raw promise methods are great for running async code concurrently.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I recently run into some problem with await so I added my answer and I would argue it is NOT "it depends" There are  one case I will prefer promise, which is promise concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [unional's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47525052/2259743):

You can achieve the same behavior as `Promise.all` with `async/await`

```
function foo() {
  Promise.all([backend.doSomething(), backend.doAnotherThing()])
    .then(([a, b]) => {
       return a + b
    })
}

async function foo() {
  const a = backend.doSomething()
  const b = backend.doAnotherThing()
  return await a + await b
}
```

Backend tasks happen concurrently and we wait on both to be finished before we return. See also the [MDN example I wrote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Examples)

Based on this I am not sure if there is any performance advantage to directly using Promises over `async/await`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer this question from the opposite direction, i.e. when to use promise over async/await. And other than these cases I think using async/await will be more appropriate.

So except for [Promise concurrency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#promise_concurrency) I will use async/await. There are **four** static methods for Promise concurrency.

The others answers have mentioned `Promise.all()` but if you need to all promise to be settled you can choose `Promise.allSettled()`

For `Promise.any()` I have a use case for it, [Is it possible to break away from await Promise.all when any promise has fulfilled (Chrome 80)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66044132/is-it-possible-to-break-away-from-await-promise-all-when-any-promise-has-fulfill)

The difference between `Promise.any()` and `Promise.race()` is `Promise.any()` rejects when all of the promises reject while `Promise.race()` rejects when any of the promises rejects.

One use case for `Promise.race()`is to implement a **timeout** because async/await doesn't have built-in support for timeout.

I will just copy the code from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-promises-in-javascript/. All the credit to the author.

```
async function fetchDataWithTimeout() {
  const timeoutPromise = new Promise((_, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Timeout exceeded')), 5000);
  });

  try {
    const response = await Promise.race([fetch('https://api.example.com/data'), timeoutPromise]);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Adding timeout function is probably **the only case** I still need to write `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...})` explicitly.

Before async/await I sometime made Promise constructor antipattern, i.e. manually creating a Promise over another promise (the return value of some web call). Using promise chain is one way to fix that antipattern but using async/await makes my codes more readable.